# Delphi 2007 VI/VIM Key Mapping

Tags: delphi, vim, ide, delphi-2007

After reading *The Pragmatic Programmer*, I became quite accustomed to VIM. When in Visual Studio I have ViEmu (http://www.viemu.com/) to provide me with VIM functionality.

Is anyone aware of a similar program/key binding/workaround to integrate VI/VIM key bindings in CodeGear Delphi 2007?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delphi's key bindings are extensible, first of all there are several keyboard mappings to choose from out of the box and then there are APIs in ToolsAPI unit to write your own (you should implement IOTAKeyboardBinding interface). I don't know about VIM but I assume it can be done with these APIs.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/petdr/vide is a very limited subset of the vi bindings that I wrote which integrates into the Delphi IDE.

It has a few quirks, but it does the job for me.

I have used it in XE2, XE8 and Berlin 10.1

Answer (score 0):

I remember seeing that in Delphi 7, but that might have been from CodeRush, a Delphi add-in that is no longer available for Delphi. . . . .

An alternative is you could use Delphi Prism in Visual Studio and keep using ViEmu . . . I know that doesn't work for your native code.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer Jim. Regretfully, CodeRush isn't available anymore. The cost of Delphi Prism is definitely a cost factor.